# How to write a file manager in android like ES File Explorer or Astro or Root Explorer (Non-rooted)?

Tags: android, file, file-manager

I have scoured all the guides I could through google including Android docs but I can't find anything on how to access the directories in internal and sdcard storage thats from recent years that doesn't involve `Storage Access Framework`. Even with `SAF` I get eaccess denied when I tried to modify a file on sdcard (actual hardware sdcard). `Environment.getExternalStorage()` is being deprecated too.

Comment: Even if it is deprecated you could start browsing that external storage directory.

Comment: And of course one can modifiy a file on removable micro SD card using SAF.